# Swipe tabs below ActionBar with based on Fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, swipe

In my application I want to implement some tabs below the action bar, which should be swipable (like SongKick app). I'm also using fragments in the rest of my app, so the solution should be based on fragments too. 
I'm a bit confused about this UI patter, as I don't know which components should I use to implement it. Regarding compatibility, can this solution be based on Android compatibility library too?
Can someone suggest some resources/tutorials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do not put tags in subject. Tags works fine here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionBar tabs(as well as ActionBarSherlock tabs to ensure backwards compatibility) and implement swipe by using a PageChangeListener on your ViewPager:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // When swiping between pages, select the
                    // corresponding tab.
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    ...
}
```

You can read that up and download a sample project from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#swipe-tabs).

Comment: Do I really need ActionBarSherlock to ensure backwards compatibility?

Comment: I would recommend that. You can use the native ActionBar but then you wouldn't support API Levels below 11. You can also do that with a Tabhost, but I wouldn't use them since they are deprecated.

Comment: Android Compatibility Library can't help here?

Comment: No, the compat lib can replace the native Fragments and the ViewPager, but not the ActionBar, because Jake Wharton's ActionBar Sherlock does a good job replacing the default ActionBar. So there is no need to include that in the lib since most Android devs already use ABS.